# Creating a pattern background for View

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uicolor

I have a view which has a patterned background. Previously I sliced the image to size so they are really large.

I think there is a better way to approach with a background color and a pattern image over the top, so the image is smaller and less memory etc.

```
buttonView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, logoView.bounds.size.height, screen.size.width, 232)];
buttonView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
//    UIImageView *bgButtonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonView.bounds.size.width, buttonView.bounds.size.height)];
//    NSString *bgButtonViewFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bg-welcomeButtonView" ofType:@"png"];
//    UIImage *bgButtonImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bgButtonViewFilePath];
//    [bgButtonView setImage:bgButtonImg];
//    [buttonView addSubview:bgButtonView];
    buttonView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-ButtonViewPattern"]];
```

In the last line I try to setup my pattern to overlay a blue color. Unfortunately the whole view shows white. If I only have blueColor it shows solid blue, so not sure if something is wrong in the above.

My image pattern is below, it is a PNG with white and transparent pixels.

[image: Pattern Image]

Comment: Have you tried including the extension in the image name?

Comment: Yes, no difference unfortunately

Comment: NOTE: I have found the issue, awaiting moderator as unable to answer own question

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pattern as a background color this way:

```
buttonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-ButtonViewPattern"]];
```

If the image is relatively small, you can make many versions of it with required overlay colors.